# AngularJS - Multiple Modules/Controllers on different pages - only selecting first controller for both pages

Tags: angularjs, module, controller, angularjs-scope

I am extremely new to AngularJS and JavaScript in general so any help would be appreciated!
I have two data sources Users and Pets - both are Array objects and I want them to display in a table on different pages of my site. I have an app.module.js which calls the module petsapp or usersapp Currently the controller only being called is the petspp.
I have tried to use $scope but I don't really know what I'm doing!

I currently have set up an **app.module.js**, which looks like this (but possibly wrong:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('petsapp',[]);
    angular.module('usersapp',[]);
})();    

another file called **Pets.controller.js:**

    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('petsapp')
        .controller('PetsController', function ($scope) {

        })


    PetsController.$inject = ['$http'];

    function PetsController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.pets = [];
        vm.getAll = getAll();
        vm.deletePet = deletePet();

        init();

        function init(){
            getAll();
        }
```

and a **users.controller.js** which looks like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('usersapp')
    .controller('UsersController', UsersController)

UsersController.$inject = ['$http'];

function UsersController($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.users = [];
    vm.getAll = getAll()
    vm.delete = deleteUser()

    init();

    function init(){
        getAll();
    }
```

my **pets html** (working) is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/angular.min.js" th:src="@{/angular.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/app/app.module.js" th:src="@{/app/app.module.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/app/pets.controller.js" th:src="@{/app/pets.controller.js}"></script></head>
    <header th:insert="fragments.html :: nav"></header>
    <body ng-app="petsapp" ng-controller="PetsController as vm">
    <!-- Page content goes here -->
    <div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
            <!-- Display animals in a table -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Breed</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>OK with Children?</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="pet in vm.pets">
                    <td>{{pet.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{pet.animalName}}</td>
                    <td>{{pet.animal}}</td>
                    <td>{{pet.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{pet.breed}}</td>
                    <td>{{pet.age}}</td>
                    <td>{{pet.compWithChildren}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>.
```

my **users html** (not working as it is only pulling the pets.controllers.js)  is:

```
    <head th:insert="fragments.html :: headerfiles">
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/angular.min.js" th:src="@{/angular.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/app/app.module.js" th:src="@{/app/app.module.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/app/users.controller.js" th:src="@{/app/users.controller.js}"></script>
    </head>
    <header th:insert="fragments.html :: nav"></header>
    <body ng-app="usersapp" ng-controller="UsersController as vm">
    <!-- Page content goes here -->
    <div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
            <!-- Display animals in a table -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Roles</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Contact Number</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="userdetail in vm.users">
                    <td>{{userdetail.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{userdetail.roles}}</td>
                    <td>{{userdetail.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{userdetail.contactNo}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <!--Only Admin can delete rows --->
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.deleteUser(userdetail.id)">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

I think the problem is in the app.module.js file where I've defined two modules?

do I need to combine both controllers into one file?  if so how do I implement that?

Comment: Just a friendly FYI... Angular.js is deprecated. If you're new to Angular, I would highly suggest learning Angular from: https://angular.io which is the latest version.

Comment: Thanks I'm just using it for a uni project, i I have been looking on there but I really don't know what to do and if I'm even implementing it properly have you any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Angular.js

Comment: What's the purpose of having two AngularJS apps (modules)? If you don't really need to (and I can't think of a good reason why you would) simply register both controllers under a single AngularJS app.

Comment: Thanks Lex - oh ok I assumed I needed two apps as I need to call in two separate tables of data to do this? how would I differentiate between the two datasets?  do I not need a module per controller

Comment: A single AngularJS app can have any number of controllers, services, components, directives, etc. You define your app (module) once and then create whatever controllers you need on that app. A typical app will use services to retrieve data from the server. You can then inject these services into your controllers and call the methods on them to retrieve your data. Most tutorials out there should go through this and it might benefit you to look through a couple.